# A generic representation of a Password Generator's result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, logic

This is more of a discussion type question. I'm working on a system that has a number of interfaces, which can be implemented in different assemblies and those assemblies would get loaded at runtime upon requirement. An example of such interface is `INotifier`. It's a generic notifier that needs to be implemented:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Company.MainModule.CentralLogging;

namespace Company.NotificationEngine
{
        public interface INotifier
        {
                 IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Dictionary<String, object> parameters,AsyncCallback callBack,object state, LogMaster logMaster);
                 Dictionary<string,object> EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult);   
        }
}
```

Now, an example of an implementation of INotifier:

```
namespace Company.NotificationEngine
{
    internal class SMSNotification : INotifier
    {

        #region Class Variables

        public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Dictionary<string, object> parameters, AsyncCallback callBack, object state, LogMaster logMaster)
        {
            // Send SMS
            return asyncResult;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            return null;
        }


        #region Private Functions

    }
}
```

Now, following the same pattern, I'm to create a generic password generator called `IGenerator`. That should have two functions: `GeneratePassword` and `ValidatePassword`. The `GeneratePassword` will generate a password based upon the algorithm the implementing assembly would define. The `ValidatePassword` is a requirement that we need as different clients have different password requirements of complexity. After a password is generated, it has to be validated.

Now, recently, we have switched to .NET Framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012. Both these methods can be time consuming. The `GeneratePassword` could be generating a simple AlphaNumeric password or a multi-page matrix of passwords. Similarly, `ValidatePassword` might be sending the generated password through HTTP to clients password validating server/API. At the moment we are using the BeginInvoke/EndInvoke pattern. I want to have `GeneratePasswordAsync` and `ValidatePasswordAsync` async-await pattern. They'll come with their respective completed and cancel options/events

**Q:** Can I use async-await pattern at interface level?

We are targeting different software, platforms, and operating systems for password resetting. So that why the generic Generator.

My next question will most-likely be the signature of both these methods as I'm trying to cover a wide range of password types and need to understand what should suffice for a return type; A simple `Object` or a `<T>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use async and await at the interface level. Remember that the async and await keywords are C# keywords that provide pre-packaged code to handle existing .Net interfaces. Either pick the .Net standard interfaces or use your own (since you probably already have them implemented).

I assume the use of "object" is there to handle other forms of authentication such as a digital certificate or a One Time Password (OTP). However, in this case, the authenticating subject may want to send a nonce for the other party to sign and the pattern you have above does not cover multiple rounds of communication.

Remember to never transmit passwords in plain text over an unencrypted channel. Otherwise, they can be sniffed off the network. You also may want to have some form of replay attack detection and both source and client authentication as, otherwise, someone could capture a call to "ValidatePassword" then replay to either authenticate successfully or lock out the account after too many incorrect logon attempts.

I know it is bad form to ask a question in the answer but how is the user name or other identity specified? Is this one of the values in the dictionary?

Comment: Actually, I do have the OTP Module separately. Also there is a Windows Domain password reset module. Both these modules require a password generated for them. We have a descent Alpha-Numeric-Special characters password generator. But we need to expand now. Also, there is no username associated here. Similarly, the implementing assembly that will do HTTP stuff will have a certificate based encrypted data transfer.

Comment: Also, `await` is used within the body of the `async` method. In case of an interface, there will be no method body. How'd I go about that.

Comment: As I said, await and async are just short cuts. Have a look at Eric Lippert's blog for a better explanation than I can give: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx. These articles say what they do "under the covers" and what interfaces they use.